# Does Elixir have coding standards or an authoritative style guide published by the language developers, like PEP8 or the Erlang Programming Rules?

Tags: coding-style, elixir

I'm pretty sure that I can just use the [Erlang](http://www.erlang.se/doc/programming_rules.shtml) style guide, but if Elixir has evolved to the point of something like PEP8, I would like to enforce it* as soon as possible.

If it's just a matter of opinion, I guess I'll just blend the Erlang style guide into the community style guide I found.

Much of the following community coding standard "The Elixir Style Guide" looks like it was borrowed from Ruby style guides:

[The Elixir Style Guide](https://github.com/niftyn8/elixir_style_guide)

[People are aware of style as a concern](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/search?q=style+guide&type=Issues&utf8=%E2%9C%93), generally, but I suspect that many of these Elixir pioneers are seasoned programmers.

Is there an authoritative style guide, like PEP8 for Python, published for Elixir-lang?

To rephrase, PEP8 is an authoritative guide published on python.org, as follows: python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008. The Elixir Style Guide, however, is a community effort, though a very nice one. might require me to look for, or develop, more on metaprogramming and macro definition.

Similarly, Erlang has its programming rules: http://www.erlang.se/doc/programming_rules.shtml

Does Elixir have an authoritative, author sanctioned style guide, y/N?

*pre-receive hoox enabled by mean, mean wadies

Comment: // , This question is prompted by two things: `My experience in Python.` My watching, just a few hours, ago, of this horror: https://youtu.be/csyL9EC0S0c?t=35m48s

Comment: // , PEP8 is an authoritative guide published on python.org, as follows: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/. The Elixir Style Guide, while very nice, might require me to look for, or develop, more on metaprogramming and macro definition. It's a community effort. I hope that the analogy between PEP8 to the Python world, and what I seek, is clear.

Comment: FWIW, there is IMHO a lot of personal opinion in that Elixir style guide. It's a reasonable attempt, but far from a community consensus.

Comment: // , The PEP8 of Elixir it is not, obviously, which makes me wonder a bit about Onorio's question.

Comment: As of Elixir 1.6 there is now a [code formatter](https://hashrocket.com/blog/posts/format-your-elixir-code-now) similar to what gofmt is for golang

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is there an authoritative style guide, like PEP8 for Python, published for Elixir-lang?

No, there is not.

Comment: Is this still the case today?

Comment: Good call. It is not the case today. Since v1.6, Elixir includes a code formatter, which is pretty much the standard.